# Как динамически обновлять описание кадра на веб странице?

Tags: python, flask

Я позаимствовал реализацию Гринберга для вставки видео на сайт средствами moution JPEG.

```
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        bboxs = processor.find_faces(frame)
        #условно эта функция обновляет текстовое описание кадра (список лиц в нем) 
        frame = append_info()
        frame = frame_2_byte(frame)
        gen_res = (b'--frame\r\n'
         b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

        yield gen_res


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera(0)),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

В шаблоне кадр вызывается следующим образом:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" height="1250 px" width="1480 px">
```

Мне требуется реализовать текстовое описание в отдельном блоке на странице для кадров из видео.

Я предполагаю, что мне необходимо сохранять значение текста в менеджере контекста сессии и написать генератор, аналогичный генератору изображений. Возможно есть варианты проще?